# create new container azure

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to migrate large data that is required for our website hosted on Azure to access. The data amounts to about 7GB. After reading few forums, I have come to know that  SQL Azure BLOB Storage can do the trick for me. Can anyone please let me know how we can store data in  SQL Azure BLOB Storage and access it?

At first I want to try to store a Test.txt file in the BLOB and access the contents of this file from our website and display it.

Thank you very much in advance

Sandeep

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean "Azure Storage Blob" and not BLOBs in SQL azure? Note that SQL Azure is "just" a SQL server hosted for you. Azure Storage (with tables and blobs and queues) is something different.

This tutorial should get you started: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jnak/archive/2010/01/11/walkthrough-windows-azure-blob-storage-nov-2009-and-later.aspx

Answer (score 0):

These [Getting Started Guides](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/services/storage/) are also good resources for ramping up on Blobs, Tables and Queues - available for .NET, Java, Node, PHP, Ruby and Python.